# $x \sinh2y=y \sin2x$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, trigonometry

I am working on a problem(in complex analysis) and I am stuck at this point,

I want to solve the following equation: $$x \sinh2y=y \sin2x$$

I can see $x=0$ or $y=0$ satisfy the equation but this deduction was purely through trial and error.

How to rigorously solve the equation? Thanks for reading out, and all the help, and hints.

Comment: If you plot the two functions $sin(2x)/x$ and $sinh(2x)/x$ you can read off all the solutions. Pick an $x$-value for one function, and then find all $x$ values of the other function with the same $y$ value. Of course this doesn't give you exact analytic solutions but it tells you how many solutions to expect and roughly what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\sinh(ix)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}=i\sin(x)$$

Here's a different angle of attack:

We know that for $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq0$ $$\sin x \leq x \quad \text{and} \quad \sinh(x)\geq x$$

We deduce that:
$$x \sinh 2y \geq 2xy  \quad \text{and} \quad y\sin 2x \leq 2xy$$

which means that $$\sinh 2y =2y  \quad \text{and} \quad  \sin2x=2x$$So that the only real solution in the first quadrant is $y=x=0$. This can be repeated for the remaining quadrants.

Comment: I can not see how to use this hint. I am sorry.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I've edited my answer to include another way of solving the equation.

Comment: @MartinR It shows that \emph{one} possible family of solutions is $y=ix$ of which only one is real, namely $x=0, y=0$ but I see that it is not completely rigorous. I've edited my answer to include another way of solving the equation.